# Hahn-Mazurkiewicz with finite one-dimensional Hausdorff measure

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Suppose that there is a continuous surjection from $[0,1]$ to a metric space $(X,d)$. If $(X,d)$ has finite one-dimensional Hausdorff measure, must there exist a Lipschitz surjection from $[0,1]$ to $(X,d)$?

I believe this to be true based on a vague memory from twenty years ago, but can't seem to find the result in Federer - which makes me a bit worried. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. It holds even under the weaker assumptions that $X$ is compact and connected with finite one-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Alberti and Ottolini ([On the structure of continua with finite length and Golab's semicontinuity theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09941)) attribute the result to a paper of Ważewski from 1927: Ważewski, Tadeusz. Kontinua prostowalne w związku z funkcjami i odwzorowaniami absolutnie ciągłemi (Rectifiable continua in connection with absolutely continuous functions and mappings). *Dodatek do Rocznika Polskiego Towarzystwa Matematycznego (Supplement to the Annals of the Polish Mathematical Society)*, (1927), 9–49.

In their Theorem 4.4, Alberti and Ottolini give a self-contained proof of a slightly stronger result. (I have not independently looked at the paper of Ważewski.)

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for the fast and complete answer! 

It is surprising to me that a finite length continuum must be locally connected. Cool!